# Не возвращается ответ из таблицы mysql

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть такая таблица: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно в зависимости от вопроса и сервера вернуть ответ. Если заполнить в пхп скрипте только сервер то все нормально но когда заполняю и вопрос ответа нет, подскажите что я делаю не так?

```php
$result = $conn->query("SELECT server, question, answer FROM drp_captch WHERE server = 'Sapphire' AND question = 'сkoльko уmоtоцикла колес imeeeтся?' COLLATE utf8_bin");

if($result === FALSE) { 
    die(mysqli_error($conn)); 
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['answer'];
}
```

Если убрать `AND question = 'сkoльko уmоtоцикла колес imeeeтся?'` то все нормально возвращает.

Comment: Чудес не бывает. Если добавление условия приводит к тому, что запись не возвращается - значит, для этой записи это условие не выполняется.

Comment: Я думаю, дело в кодировке. ср1251 и utf8 - немного разные вещи.

Answer (score -1):

Оберните поле server в знакт ``

```
SELECT `server`, question, answer FROM drp_captch WHERE `server` = 'Sapphire' AND question = 'сkoльko уmоtоцикла колес imeeeтся?' COLLATE utf8_bin"
```